# StringBuilder like PreparedStatement

Tags: java, stringbuilder

It there a way to create strings like we create PreparedStatements? I mean to create whole string with '?' where I need insert values later and then insert this values based on condition. In the StringBuilder I didn't find such functionality, only append or insert by offset.

Comment: You need to create custom methods to do so. There is no built-in functionality to do it.

Comment: Does it have to be StringBuilder, or would String.format(template", arguments...) be suitable?

Comment: Is it important to use the '?' character as placeholder?

Comment: @TheLostMind 'public StringBuilder replace(int start, int end, String str)' this is signature of the method, it means that I need manually calculate start and end. So, one possibility is implement this functionality by myself as **Darshan Lila** said.

Comment: @RogerLindsjö no, it doesn't have to be StringBuilder I just looking for such functionality.

Comment: @cy3er, no it can be any something another conspicuous.

Comment: @Anatoly What's wrong about `String.format(String pattern, Object... args)`?

Comment: @AlexR, nothing, I didn't know that it exists. Will give a try. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is from MessageFormat's javadoc:

```
 int planet = 7;
 String event = "a disturbance in the Force";

 String result = MessageFormat.format(
     "At {1,time} on {1,date}, there was {2} on planet {0,number,integer}.",
     planet, new Date(), event);
```

The output is:

```
 At 12:30 PM on Jul 3, 2053, there was a disturbance in the Force on planet 7.
```

You can see that simple inserts are possible ({2}) but more sophisticated ones as well.

Comment: Cool, I didn't know about such a nice formatter with actually well-readable format strings :) (+1)

Comment: @AlexR java.text is a much-neglected package containing an odd assortment of classes for various purposes. Some of them may appear to be outlandish, but they are heaven-sent when needed, e.g., RuleBasedCollator.

Comment: Thanks I'll look into that whenever I'm about to write another String helper function :)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need a `StringBuilder` to do this, the method `String.format(String pattern, Object... args)` suits your needs.
Simply specify the pattern with placeholders of the form `%s` for `String` or `%d` for Integers (including `long`), `%f` for Floats (including `double`). For a full documentation of the format, see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax).
Example:

```
String message = String.format("Hello, %1$s! It is %2$tm %2$te,%2$tY", name, new Date());
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [String.format()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-).

The general idea is that you provide a [format string](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) and give the actual values.

It looks like this:

```
final String name = "Anatoly";
final Calendar birthday = ...;     
String.format("%1's birthday is on %2$tm %2$te,%2$tY", name, birthday);
```

If you want to have it more similar to the `PreparedStatement`, make your own wrapper class on top of this:

```
public class PreparedString {
    final private String format;
    public PreparedString(String format) {
        this.format = format;
    }
    public String getString(Object... args) {
        return String.format(format, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Formatter is useful for this. The shortcut would be String.format() as already mentioned

see:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax

Comment: You should given an example - link-only replies are discouraged on SO and liable to be closed.